# NODE_PATH is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install this (https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose) nodejs application in my windows7.

But I always get this:

```
NODE_PATH is not recognizes as internal or external command
```

For solving this I set a system variable using this command :

```
setx NODE_PATH "C:\Users\ussr\Application Data\npm\node_modules"
```

Also tried control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3 too.

But still it says **NODE_PATH is not recognized**.

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

your command is error

```
setx NODE_PATH "C:\Users\ussr\Application Data\npm\node_modules"

set NODE_PATH "C:\Users\ussr\Application Data\npm\node_modules"
```

Comment: I think you are talking about `set NODE_PATH = C:\Users\ussr\Application Data\npm\node_modules`.  Yes I tried and it does not work too

Comment: you must edit environment  variable instead of using "set". Because "set" is valid just under current bash.

Comment: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/